# How to verify domain name with SAN in pyOpenSSL

Tags: pyopenssl

I'm using pyOpenSSL 17.5.0 to perform certificate chain verification, and I also want to verify if the requested domain name matches the SAN provided in X509Extension.

My current thoughts are to extract DNS list from extensions and perform a regex mapping manually. But shouldn't the pyOpenSSL library to provide this function? I can't find anything useful in its documents...